# MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA is deprecated and contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r") cost much time. How do I check Uri exists?

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I used `File.exsits()` to check `File` that path is provided by `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` exists. But now (start from Android10), `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is deprecated. So I use `ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r")` to check it exists. But `ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r")` cost more time.

The following code snippet shows how I check it now. But I don't know app that in `scoped external storage` can get `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` and the return value of `File.exsits()` correctly everytime. Who has a better way to solve this problem? Thanks!

```java
        ...
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(prefix, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)));
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = null;
        try {
            // Although path is deprecated, use path to check file exists first, because openAssetFileDescriptor cost long time
            // I don't find other method.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                assetFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                if (assetFileDescriptor == null) {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                File file = new File(path);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    path = null;
                    assetFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                    if (assetFileDescriptor == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null
        }finally{
            FileUtil.closeSilently(assetFileDescriptor);
        }
        ....
```

Comment: Just try to open an InputStream on the uri.

Comment: `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(...).exists()`, where `...` is your document `Uri`.

Comment: @blackapps open inputStream cost more time than File.exsits

Comment: You cannot use File.exists(). So what you say does not make sense.

Comment: @blackapps There are 1000 photos in my phone. It will cost about 500 miliseconds if I use `File.exsits`, however it will cost 4 seconds if I try to open inputStream.

Comment: And is there any difference between openAssetFileDescriptor() and opening an input stream?

Comment: @blackapps 

```java
AssetFileDescriptor fd = openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r", null);
            try {
                return fd != null ? fd.createInputStream() : null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to create stream");
            }
```

It is in the method `openInputStream` .

Comment: ???? I asked you is there was any time difference in using openAssetFileDescriptor and just openening an InputStream. `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`.

Comment: openInputStream internally calls openAssetFileDescriptor() followed by createInputStream()